# Sudo still asking for my password

Tags: 16.04, command-line, sudo

I just added my user to the `sudoers` file:

```
$ grep username /etc/sudoers
  username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

$ sudo -l

  User can run on localhost following commands (translated by myself):
  (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
  (ALL : ALL) ALL
```

However when using `sudo` it still asks for my password. What am I missing?

Comment: Add the output of `sudo -l`, please

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: So there's another rule in sudoers which comes after your rule. Put your rule at the end, or in a file in `sudoers.d`